# Stripe One Time payment or Single Payment is not working using laravel/cashier

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, laravel-cashier

I am trying to setup Stripe one time payment in an application but getting this error. I am using laravel package for stripe i.e laravel/cashier

```
As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports
```

I have added the description as per regulations provided by stripe in code but still I am facing this issue.

This is the code I am using:

```
$user = auth()->user(); $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method; try { $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer(); $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod, [ 'currency' => 'INR', 'description' => 'Software development services', ]); $user->charge($request->fees*100, $paymentMethod, ['off_session' => true]); } catch (\Exception $exception) { dd($exception->getMessage()); }
```

First currency was in `USD`. I have changed currency from

```
USD
```

to

```
INR
```

but still getting this.

Meanwhile in my stripe dashboard, Payment is in incomplete mode.

I have used all possible fix but it is not working.
Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: Could you provide the complete textual representation of the error you receive in the console when you app attempts to make this request?

Additionally if you could provide the version of laravel-cashier (and laravel) you are using that will likely help troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports

Comment: This is the error I am getting and also

Comment: I am using Laravel 8 and Laravel/cashier latest version

Comment: The link you shared suggests this is a beta feature.  Have you enrolled in this Beta?

Comment: I haven't enrolled anything. @RyanM

Comment: Well, based on the URL included in the error message, it would appear you cannot do what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to accept payment (in India) from customers outside of India?

Answer (score 0):

I am also experienced this error. The reason might be that the account is set to Indian. If you create a new account with the country set to USA, your payment should go through successfully. The payment status is incomplete possibly due to certain rules or regulations for payments in India. Therefore, creating an account with the USA and trying the payment again could resolve the issue.